# Windows phone:Feed large string into database table

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I am designing an rss reader app where I'm storing all the info in a database table.Now I'm getting the following error when I try to save the full story to the table.

```
Error in saving article to database:
System.InvalidOperationException: String truncation: max=4000, len=27771, 
value =
'<div class="track"><img alt="" src="http://hits.thegu.....<rest of the string>'
```

How to store this large string in the database?

Comment: Store it as a file in isolated storage and save the file location to database, not the content.

Answer (score 1):

That helps me (additional params DbType and UpdateCheck):

```
[Column(DbType="ntext", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string Text {
  // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.Linq.DataContext uses NVARCHAR(4000) as default mapping for string. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx.

You may implement a custom Linq to Sql mapping but then you would still require the max length of string beforehand. Best alternative is to save it in a file in isolated storage